# Python3 PyQT5 float variable to LineEdit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.8, qlineedit

I am trying to put the float result of a calculation into a LineEdit in PyQT5. I know the LineEdit reference is correct as I can change the text to a set value, eg "Test", but I can't setText to display my calculated variable.
All the equations etc are working correctly and print to shell, it is just the output to GUI I am struggling with.
I need to do the float conversion as the logic refuses to work if I don't. Do I need to convert it back to something else to get it to work with setText?
I have put #Default data examples and answers for each stage in the code.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
import sys
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np

class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
       super(Ui,self).__init__() 
       uic.loadUi('BinGrid.ui',self) 

     
       self.button=self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton,'P6BGCbtn') 
       self.button.clicked.connect(self.P6_to_BGC) 
    
    
       self.show() ## Show the Gui

   def P6_to_BGC(self,MainWindow):  #### Find Bin Grid centre from Bin Grid Origin ####        

       BinX=self.BinXin.text()   ## Default set to 6.25 in Qt Designer
       BinY=self.BinYin.text() ## Default set to 6.25
       L_Theta=self.L_Thetain.text() ## Default set to 329.075
       BGO_E=self.BGO_Ein.text() ## Default set to 123456.123
       BGO_N=self.BGO_Nin.text() ## Default set to 1234567.123

       BinX=float(BinX)
       BinY=float(BinY)
       L_Theta=float(L_Theta)
       Line_Theta=np.radians(L_Theta)
       BGO_E=float(BGO_E)
       BGO_N=float(BGO_N)

       Bin_Theta=np.arctan((0.5*BinX)/(0.5*BinY))                
       Bin_Hyp=((0.5*BinX)**2+(0.5*BinY)**2)**0.5
       BGC_E=round(BGO_E+Bin_Hyp*np.sin(Bin_Theta+Line_Theta),3) ## Output is 123457.075
       BGC_N=round(BGO_N+Bin_Hyp*np.cos(Bin_Theta+Line_Theta),3) ## Output is 1234571.287       
        


       self.BGC_Ein.setText('BGC_E') ## This works to set the box to 'BGC_E'
       self.BGC_Ein.repaint() ## Corrects for know 'non-display until focus' bug
       self.BGC_Nin.setText(BGC_N.text()) ## This doesn't work to set the text to the value of my variable
       self.BGC_Nin.repaint()

app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) 
window=Ui() 
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QLineEdit.setText()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#text-prop) expects a string parameter, so you have to convert your float to string first. E.g.:

```
self.BGC_Nin.setText(str(BGC_N))
```

Also, you could use string formatting to round your numbers, so that you don't have to call `round()` yourself. E.g.:

```
BGC_N = BGO_N+Bin_Hyp*np.cos(Bin_Theta+Line_Theta) ## Output is 1234571.287       
self.BGC_Ein.setText("{:.3f}".format(BGC_N))
```